# Angular 1.3.8 routing not working without errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I am following a book called MEAN Machine. The code from the part in this book in question can be found at [this Github Repo](https://github.com/scotch-io/mean-machine-code/tree/master/12-angular-routing).

When clicking the links in `/public/views/index.html` which should be routed, I get file not found errors in the web browser.

The code (`/public/js/app.routes.js`) that does not seem to work:

```
// inject ngRoute for all our routing needs
angular.module('routerRoutes', ['ngRoute'])

// configure our routes
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'views/pages/home.html',
        controller  : 'homeController',
        controllerAs: 'home'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : 'views/pages/about.html',
        controller  : 'aboutController',
        controllerAs: 'about'
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : 'views/pages/contact.html',
        controller  : 'contactController',
        controllerAs: 'contact'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

In the index.html file, we are pointing to the correct files:

```
<script src="js/app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

To test their code, I changed the base tag in index.html to my folder's path which eliminated errors of not finding the above files.

Is this material dated? Also, I realize this book is not using Angular 2. Does Angular 2 vary drastically in routing and is this material deprecated?

Comment: angular2 is very very different than angular1.

Comment: Just to be clear...you are running this on a localhost or other server and not by using `file/open` in browser?

Comment: @charlietfl Actually, I have been doing file/open in browser. The book I have did not mention having to _run_ anything other than the backend server.

Comment: So the problem with that is you can't do ajax from `file://` protocol, and the templates are loaded using ajax. This is due to browser security restrictions, nothing to do with angular or javascript

Comment: Thanks. I am extremely new to JS/Angular/web dev in general but after your help I found out that I had to run `npm start`. Is this worth continuing or should I be looking for Angular 2 guides since, from what I can tell, it seems routing is very different from what I have been learning?

Comment: There are a lot of other learning curves for angular2 also so that is really an opinion question that is hard to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply run command

```
node server.js
```

from '12-angular-routing' directory and open in browser http://localhost:8080

The problem is that browsers by default does not allow AJAX requests to files located on your local file system. In this case you should run your local server which serves client application(server.js is simple express server).